# Hiding a specific no of div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say i have following html structure-

```
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<a>more..</a>
```

I want to hide all except the first 5 div on page load, then on click of `more` link I want to show further 5 div and so on till last div.

How can I do this using jquery?

Comment: why not hide initialy with css and show later on with javascript

Comment: Do you mean "on page load, hide all but the first 5 divs. On each click, show 5 more until all are visible"?

Comment: @Shawn Chin- why means what..in this way i want to show my data..

Comment: i think you all are getting me in opposite way...i want to show first five on load..then show next five on click of more..again next five untill all are visible

Comment: Why there is so much down-votes..i asked any thing wrong or what..i am not getting why you people are doing this to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want to do is, on page load, hide all but the first 5 divs. Then when the "more" link is clicked, show 5 more divs until all are visible

Here's how I would do it: (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HC4KW/2/)

1. By default, have all you divs visible and the "more" link hidden using CSS. This allows non-js browsers to still see your content
2. On document ready, hide all but the first 5 divs

   ```
   $("div:gt(4)", container).hide();
   ```
3. Show your "more" link which, on click:

   - Displays the first 5 hidden divs
   - hides the "more" link if there are no more hidden divs

     ```
     $('#more').show().click(function() {
         var hidden_divs = $("div:hidden", container);  /* list of hidden divs */
         if (hidden_divs.size() <= 5) {  /* No hidden divs left after we show 5 more*/
             $(this).hide();  /* hide "more" link */
         }
         hidden_divs.slice(0, 5).slideDown();  /* reveal first 5 hidden divs */
     });
     ```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (hidden_divs.size() <= 0)`?

Comment: @vzwick Nope. At that point, the divs have not been revealed yet. This saves having to do another query for hidden divs.

Comment: No probs. It shows that my comments weren't descriptive enought perhaps? Updated.

Comment: Nah. It shows that I'm way too tired to be reading code right now.

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you wanted to do is hide all divs and then clicking on `more` show the 5 next divs each time. You can try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjYKY/).

HTML:

```
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<a id="more">more..</a>
```

JS using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $('#more').click(function() {
        $('div:hidden').slice(0,5).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div:gt(4)").hide();

    $("a").click(function() {
        if ($("div:hidden").length > 5) $("div:hidden:lt(5)").show();
        else $("div:hidden").show();
    })

})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/dfL8q/1/

Comment: Awesome UX, man … When I click on "more", seeing "less" is exactly what I expected :p (SNCR, no offense)

Comment: @vzwick - excellent point well made. Everything should be more intuitive now!

Comment: @pr101- yes now you got me..+1

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div").hide()
$("div:lt(5)").show()

$("a").click(function() {
    $("div:hidden:lt(5)").show()
})

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KaPNa/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get the question right.

```
$(function() {
  $("div:gt(4)").hide();
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    $("div:hidden:lt(5)").show();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uzovug/6

Answer (score 0):

To hide five elements you could do:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var div = $('div:visible').filter(function(i){
       if (i <5) return this;
    }).hide();    


});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sbpkR/

EDIT - of course use a function to hide them on dom ready:

```
var hide5 = function(){
        var div = $('div:visible').filter(function(i){
           if (i <5) return this;
        }).hide();    
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    hide5();
    $(a).click(hide5);
});
```

EDIT 2 - I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sbpkR/2/

```
$('div').hide();
$('div').filter(function(i){
       if (i <5) return this;
 }).show();     
$('button').click(function(){
    var divS = $('div:visible:last').nextAll().filter(function(i){
       if (i <5) return this;
   })    ;
        $('div').hide();
    divS.show();


});
```

EDIT 3 - http://jsfiddle.net/sbpkR/3/

```
$('div').hide();
$('div').filter(function(i){
       if (i <5) return this;
 }).show();     
$('button').click(function(){
    var divS = $('div:visible:last').nextAll().filter(function(i){
       if (i <5) return this;
   })    ;
    divS.show();


});
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is..onload show only first five div..then on click of more show next five, if i clicked again on more then show next five....in this way

Comment: you are not getting the quetion i think..i want just opposite of what you have written.

Comment: Look At @Shawn Chin answer...i want that thing..any way thanks for your assistance..